# RecyclerView sets all the items when single data changed in database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-diffutils, room

I am using LiveData to fetch 30 items from the database like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30")
fun getLast30(): LiveData<List<Person>>
```

Every recycler view item has a like button and I have an interface in the adapter:

```
interface OnItemClickedAdapter {
    fun onFavButtonClicked(position: Int)
}
```

end when the like button clicked I am updating a single item in the database. As I am using LiveData it is fetching updated 30 items. I am setting that data using **observe** metod:

```
 viewModel.last30.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
      adapter.submitList(it)
 }
```

***Problem:***

- When Clicked a like button, the recycler view is refreshing all its contents and it scrolls to the first item.

*Edited:*
submitList(list: List) method:

```
fun submitList(persons: List<Person>) {
    val diffResult: DiffUtil.DiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
        ApodGalleryAdapterDiffCallback(
            this.persons,
            persons
        )
    )
    this.persons = person
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

DiffUtill class:

```kotlin
class PersonAdapterDiffCallback(var oldList: List<Person>, var newList: List<Person>) :
    DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].url == newList[newItemPosition].url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }

}
```

Adapter class:

```kotlin
class ApodGalleryAdapter() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ApodGalleryAdapter.ApodGalleryViewHolder>() {

    var onItemClickedGalleryAdapter: OnItemClickedGalleryAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ApodGalleryViewHolder {
        return ApodGalleryViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_apod_gallery, parent, false),
            onItemClickedGalleryAdapter
        )
    }

    private var apods: List<Apod> = ArrayList()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return apods.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ApodGalleryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindData(apods[position], position)
    }

    fun submitList(apods: List<Apod>) {

        val diffResult: DiffUtil.DiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
            ApodGalleryAdapterDiffCallback(
                this.apods,
                apods
            )
        )

        this.apods = apods

        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    class ApodGalleryViewHolder(
        itemView: View,
        var onItemClickedGalleryAdapter: OnItemClickedGalleryAdapter?
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val apodImage: ImageView = itemView.image_item_apod
        private val apodTitle: TextView = itemView.title_item_apod
        private val apodDescription: TextView = itemView.description_item_apod
        private val apodCopyright: TextView = itemView.copyright_item_apod

        fun bindData(apod: Apod, position: Int) {
            when {
                apod.url.endsWith(".jpg") -> {
                    Glide.with(apodImage.context)
                        .load(apod.url)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.transparent)
                        .into(apodImage)
                }
                apod.url.contains("youtube") -> {
                    Glide.with(apodImage.context)
                        .load(getThumbnailUrl(apod.url))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.transparent)
                        .into(apodImage)
                }
                else -> {
                    apodImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent)
                }
            }
            apodTitle.text = apod.title
            apodDescription.text = apod.explanation
            apodCopyright.text = apod.copyright

            if (apod.isLiked) {
                itemView.fav_button_item_apod_gallery.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_favorite_24)
            } else {
                itemView.fav_button_item_apod_gallery.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_favorite_border_24)
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickedGalleryAdapter?.onClick(apod.date)
            }
            itemView.fav_button_item_apod_gallery.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickedGalleryAdapter?.onFavButtonClicked(position)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
interface OnItemClickedGalleryAdapter {

    fun onClick(date: String)

    fun onFavButtonClicked(position: Int)
}
```

```kotlin
class ApodGalleryAdapterDiffCallback(var oldList: List<Apod>, var newList: List<Apod>) :
    DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].url == newList[newItemPosition].url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }

}
```

I have overwritten the `equals()` method of my Data class:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {

    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass)
        return false

    other as Apod

    if (id != other.id)
        return false

    if (copyright != other.copyright)
        return false

    if (date != other.date)
        return false

    if (explanation != other.explanation)
        return false

    if (hdUrl != other.hdUrl)
        return false

    if (media_type != other.media_type)
        return false

    if (service_version != other.service_version)
        return false

    if (url != other.url)
        return false

    if (isLiked != other.isLiked)
        return false

    return true
}
```

Comment: You need to use api `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: That's how it works...you are observing whole list change - not change inside list... Did you notify recycler view that you have stable ids?

Comment: Yes, I am using `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` @Rohit. But as @Selvin stated above I am observing the database. Can you suggest a reliable solution for this?

Comment: are you using `DiffUtil`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `DiffUtil` @Ehsanmsz

Comment: @Javlon so you don't need to call `notifyItemChanged()`, please add your adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was such a fool searching the solution througth **liveData**, **DiffUtill** and `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)`

The real problem was in my observer block:

```
    viewModel.apod30Days.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        adapter.submitList(it)
        adapter.onItemClickedGalleryAdapter = object : OnItemClickedGalleryAdapter {
            override fun onClick(date: String) {
                val intent =
                    Intent(requireActivity().applicationContext, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.APOD_DATE_KEY, date)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            override fun onFavButtonClicked(position: Int) {
                val apod = it[position]
                apod.isLiked = !apod.isLiked
                viewModel.updateApod(apod)
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
            }
        }
        if (it.size < 30)
            viewModel.setLast30Apods()
        binding.apodViewPager.adapter = adapter
    })
```

In this block's last line, I am setting the adapter again and again when the liveData changes. DiffUtill was working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

in `DiffUtil` implementation, `areContentsTheSame` always returns `false`.

```kotlin
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition] // always returns false
}
```

you have to check each variable like this:

```kotlin
//for example
data class Person(
    val name:String,
    val age:Int
)
```

```kotlin
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
    val oldItem = oldList[oldItemPosition]
    val newItem = newList[newItemPosition]

    return oldItem.name.equals(newItem.name) && 
               oldItem.age == newItem.age
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I have overitten my equals() method. But didn't helped.